# Could anyone tell me what the "robby ( robbie? ) way" is?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing an English blog. I am currently listening to Trump and Clinton debate over the abortion, could anyone tell me what the "robby (robbie) way" is?

I looked up the dictionary and surfed through but nothing came up. Is it possibly a name???

[Video clip of Clinton/Trump Debate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfdRmnT0Weo)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are thinking of [**Roe vs Wade**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v._Wade) which is a landmark decision by the Supreme Court on abortion rights for women.

Comment: So are the announcer and Hillary saying or speaking as ro-e-wade?

Comment: Hillary says "we should not reverse Roe v Wade" [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToF1Mur8QbI&t=2m06s) (roe-vee-wade) instead of saying Roe versus Wade

Comment: You need to say  clearly that you  have included a link to the d**e**bate, say it is a YouTube clip.  Frankly I had no idea what "robbie" was referring to until Peter explained in the comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about something that was heard incorrectly and the value of keeping it "open" for other learners is low.

Comment: Okay....but you know, I can understand other words they speak completely, but if you do not know speficially, like this Roe-verus-Wade, which even Hillary omits the word "versus" and which is quit unfamiliar with learners, then it is hard to think what that would be! Sorry.

Comment: I'm sure if Hillary spoke "Roe **versus** Wade" then, I would not have asked here. Because you can guess very easily.

Comment: @KentaroTomono: It's not so much that no one else might have similar difficulty hearing this properly as that anyone with the same problem would probably not be able to find this question any more easily than they would be able to figure out the original.

Comment: You are so severe...if everybody could understand what Roe-V-Wade is without even looking up, then there would be no question here, I think.

Comment: So you guys's standard is, **no mishearding** here???? It sounds like that to me.

Comment: And I am sorry, even Peter's Wade's last D sounds weak ( I think ). Thank made me more confused,

Comment: @KentaroTomono There are many people here who aren't "guys", and the policy is that we can't serve as a transcription service for YouTube videos. If you have a question about an English usage, we are very happy to help. Do you now understand what "Roe v. Wade" refers to? If you do, we have no further service to render you, earnestly though we might wish to do so. (_Mishear**d**ing_ is not an English word.)

Comment: Transcription? I am sorry to say this, but I simply did not catch it correctly therefore was not able to understand.......though thank you for those who replied.